# jQuery: each not iterating over each item ID

Tags: jquery, loops

I have some HTML like this, where ID represents the persons Gamertag:

```
<img src="image.png" id="Blah">
<img src="image.png" id="Someone">
<img src="image.png" id="Blah">
```

I need to `css()` on each one, so I tried using `each()` to cover conditions where there are duplicates like above.

I ran this as a test:

```
$( "#Blah" ).each(function( index ) {
  console.log( index + ": " + $(this).text() );
```

But it only returned 1 result. What should I be using to iterate that covers duplicates?

Comment: An `id` should be unique on the page. Use classes instead.

Comment: `ID`s ***MUST*** be unique.  Iterate over tag `$('img')` or class name

Comment: Why any thinking person  would actually give more than one thing the _same_ id is beyond me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to use `class` instead of `id` as `id` is a unique attribute of an element

```
<img src="image.png" class="Blah">
<img src="image.png" class="Blah">
<img src="image.png" class="Blah">
```

Then iterate using the `class name`

```
$(".Blah").each(function() {
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ZHLpZ/)

Answer (score 1):

The reason you can not have ID as a sector is because all images have different IDs and .each() method will be used only one per id. Technically you want `each()` method to iterate through all images so you need something that relates to all you images like a class for each img or a wrapper for all images which you can use as selector for images. This example is based on parent div `div-img` selector. Another answer here by Khawer Zeshan is based on class selector. Pick whichever method that makes more sense from development point of view.

Say if you want to access all images in a DIV with id `div-img` and you have HTML like below:

```
<div id="div-img">
   <img src="image.png" id="Blah">
   <img src="image.png" id="Someone">
   <img src="image.png" id="Blah">
</div>
```

Here's how you can access all images within that specific div:

```
$("#div-img img").each(function( index ) { 
    console.log( index + ": " + $(this).text())
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/trzMj/1/